# Qmail Toaster and Squirrelmail SSL config location

Tags: ssl, email, squirrelmail

I've been racking my brain and Google to try and find where the location of the SSL config is located for my Qmail / Squirrelmail install.

I've installed SSL certs for Apache before, where I specify inside of the proper virtualhost section where the SSL cert is located, but am unable to find it for the services above.

Inside of the httpd.conf, there are two include file additions which are for Qmail Toaster and Squirrelmail, but when I edit the files, they don't specify locations for the SSL cert they're using.

thanks for the help!

---

Hmm, I thought I found it there for second.  In /var/qmail/control, theres a .pem file that qmail uses by default, but I changed the contents and still no go.

The thing thats throwing me is that there should be a place the specifically defines where the SSL private key and cert is located, and I can't find where thats at.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if we know what distro you were using for this install.

On a standard type install, you may find that the SSL is defined in an include file that applies to the server as a whole (and not just the VirtualHost). Look through all of the files in the /etc/http direct and see if you can find something that defines SSL. Some distributions have a wildcard include of all configs in a sub folder that defines SSL site wide. Look for that subdirectory.

Also, look in /etc/pki/tls/certs, /etc/ssl, /etc/openssl to see if there are default certs on the system. You might also want to look at /var/qmail/control and see if there are any pem files.

Answer (score 0):

```
-bash-3.2# ls -al /var/qmail/control/*.pem
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root    qmail    33 Mar 24 16:43 /var/qmail/control/clientcert.pem -> /var/qmail/control/servercert.pem
-rw-------  1 qmaild  qmail   245 Mar 24 16:43 /var/qmail/control/dh1024.pem
-rw-------  1 qmaild  qmail   156 Mar 24 16:43 /var/qmail/control/dh512.pem
-rw-------  1 qmaild  qmail   497 Mar 24 16:43 /var/qmail/control/rsa512.pem
-rw-r-----  1 qmaild  qmail  2144 Mar 24 16:43 /var/qmail/control/servercert-.pem
-rw-r-----  1 qmaild  qmail  7219 Mar 24 16:54 /var/qmail/control/servercert.pem
-bash-3.2#
```